# NSVisualEffectView fade animation

Tags: swift, macos, core-animation

How can I make a fade in／fade out animation on NSVisualEffectView.
I have used NSAnimationContext, but it just disappear without animation.

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
            context.duration = 0.5
            blurView.animator().alphaValue = 0
}, completionHandler: {
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the alpha of a `NSVisualEffectView`. Neither directly nor through animations.

Comment: How can I make a fade in／fade out animation on it? By change effect or other way.

Comment: Like I said, it is not possible.

Comment: @JinyuMeng : As Oskar said, it's not possible to fade a NSVisualEffectView by itself. But if your view is the contentView of a window, you can try to directly fade the window itself. Works great.